# Could not deduce (CI.MonadCatchIO (Handler App (AuthManager App))) in Snap handler

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I'm using an openapi-based library within a handler; unfortunately it throws a lot of network or http exceptions, so I'm attempting to use Control.Monad.CatchIO with it, but banging my head against the types.

This is where I'm at:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import qualified Control.Exception as E
import qualified Control.Monad.CatchIO as CI (try,MonadCatchIO)
import           Control.Monad.State

import           Snap
import           Application
import           Services
import qualified Helper.Heist as H
import           Snap.AzureAdAuth

-- this is the function that throws the exceptions
runQuery :: (Produces req accept, MimeUnrender accept b1, Show b1, MimeType contentType) => ServicesRequest req contentType b1 accept -> Handler App (AuthManager App) (Either MimeError b1)
runQuery r = ...


runQuery' :: forall req accept contentType b1. (Produces req accept, MimeUnrender accept b1, Show b1, MimeType contentType)
                       => ServicesRequest req contentType b1 accept
                       -> Handler App (AuthManager App) (Either E.SomeException (Either MimeError b1))
runQuery' req = 
  CI.try $ runQuery req :: Handler App (AuthManager App) (Either E.SomeException (Either MimeError b1))
```

Compiling gives this error message:

```
    * Could not deduce (CI.MonadCatchIO
                          (Handler App (AuthManager App)))
        arising from a use of `CI.try'
      from the context: (Produces req accept, MimeUnrender accept b1,
                         Show b1, MimeType contentType)
        bound by the type signature for:
                   runQuery' :: forall req accept contentType b1.
                                       (Produces req accept, MimeUnrender accept b1, Show b1,
                                        MimeType contentType) =>
                                       ServicesRequest req contentType b1 accept
                                       -> Handler
                                            App
                                            (AuthManager App)
                                            (Either E.SomeException (Either MimeError b1))
        at src/Helper/API.hs:(96,1)-(99,102)
    * In the expression: CI.try $ runQuery req
      In an equation for runQuery':
          runQuery' req = CI.try $ runQuery req
```

Any thoughts on how to line up the types?

Comment: Are those internal modules, or from a package? do you know where `Handler` is from? If it's the one from Control.Exception or `Lens`, it seems a bit of an odd thing to return from a request handler. This question badly needs more context about what you are using, what you are trying to do, and how you got to what you currently have.

Comment: One thing I can tell you: Unless this `Handler` is a monad, `try` is the wrong function. That's the meaning of the error message: there is no instance of `MonadCatchIO` for the type `Handler App (AuthManager App)`.

Comment: Hi @Ari, it is a handler defined in the [Snap framework](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-1.1.3.1/docs/Snap-Snaplet.html#t:Handler), it's definitely a monad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce your example exactly, because there are still many types for which I don't know where they're coming from.

The Snap framework's `Handler` monad uses [`MonadBaseControl`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control-1.0.2.3/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Control.html#t:MonadBaseControl) to embed the `IO` monad, rather than the more traditional mtl-style `MonadIO` and `MonadCatchIO` that `MonadCatchIO-mtl` uses.

Instead, the [`lifted-base`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lifted-base) package provides primitives such as `try` (in `Control.Exception.Lifted`) for these embeddings.

The following code compiles for me:

```
import Snap.Snaplet
import Control.Exception.Lifted hiding (Handler)

runQuery :: Handler a b c
runQuery = undefined

runQuery' :: (Exception e) => Handler a b (Either e a1)
runQuery' = try runQuery
```

Happy Haskelling!